# FOR loops : Finding value of pi using a series - absurd output

Tags: c, for-loop

QUESTION : Find value of pi using the series : 
pi = 4 – 4/3 + 4/5 – 4/7 + ... + ((-1)^(n-1)) 4/(2n+1) + ...

And my code is :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main () {

int n,i;
float pi;

printf("Enter number of terms : \n");
scanf("%d",&n);
pi = 0 ; 
for(i=1 ; i<n ; i++) {

    if (i%2==0)
         pi = pi + (4/(2*i)+1);
    else
         pi = pi - (4/(2*i)+1);



}

printf("value of pi is %f \n",pi);



return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is

```
value of pi is -1.000000
```

(for ANY odd input)

and

```
value of pi is -2.000000
```

(for ANY even input)

I know there might be some other methods to do this one. But I wish to know what's wrong with this one. I think there is a problem in

```
 if(i%2==0)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
4/(2*i)
```

This is integer division, change it to:

```
4.0/(2*i)
```

Comment: `4.f` seems better (`pi` is a `float`)